# Find all possible combinations of 25 and 50 paisa coins that adds upto change of 5 rupees

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to find a pythonic way to find all combinations of 25 and 50 paisa coins that adds upto change of 5 Rs.

I am new to python and wonder if itertools.combination or itertools.permutaion can help me find this value.

```
Expected output
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 0 + 50 Paisa x 10 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 2 + 50 Paisa x 9  = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 4 + 50 Paisa x 8  = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 6 + 50 Paisa x 7  = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 8 + 50 Paisa x 6  = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 10 + 50 Paisa x 5 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 12 + 50 Paisa x 4 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 14 + 50 Paisa x 3 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 16 + 50 Paisa x 2 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 18 + 50 Paisa x 1 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 20 + 50 Paisa x 0 = 5 Rs.
```

Comment: can you provide any example ?

Comment: Also please provide non-pythonic code you can write. Otherwise it's unclear that you made any attempt to solve the problem yourself. It'll also become clear what you want.

Comment: Paisa = ​1⁄64 rupee
5 rupees = 320 paisas
320/25 = 12.8
So it is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to this

```
coins = []

num_of_coins_25_paisa = 500/25

for i in range(num_of_coins_25_paisa+1):
    sum_of_25_paisa = 25*i
    remaining_amount = 500 - sum_of_25_paisa

    if remaining_amount % 50 == 0:
        coins.append((i,remaining_amount/50))

i = 1
for group in coins:
    print "Combination #1 : 25 Paisa x {0} + 50 Paisa x {1}  = 5 Rs.".format(group[0],group[1])
```

Output:

```
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 0 + 50 Paisa x 10 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 2 + 50 Paisa x 9 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 4 + 50 Paisa x 8 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 6 + 50 Paisa x 7 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 8 + 50 Paisa x 6 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 10 + 50 Paisa x 5 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 12 + 50 Paisa x 4 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 14 + 50 Paisa x 3 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 16 + 50 Paisa x 2 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 18 + 50 Paisa x 1 = 5 Rs.
Combination #1: 25 Paisa x 20 + 50 Paisa x 0 = 5 Rs.
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possible solution using combinations / permutations functions in python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimal solution to find combinations of any set of given coins that adds upto the any total amount.

```
def change(amount, coins_available, coins_so_far):
    if sum(coins_so_far) == amount:
            yield coins_so_far
    elif sum(coins_so_far) > amount:
            pass
    elif coins_available == []:
            pass
    else:
            for c in change(amount, coins_available[:], coins_so_far+[coins_available[0]]):
                    yield c
            for c in change(amount, coins_available[1:], coins_so_far):
                    yield c

amount = 500
coins = [5, 25]

solutions = [s for s in change(amount, coins, [])]
i = 1
for s in solutions:
    print str(i) + " : " + str(s)
    i += 1

print 'optimal solution:', min(solutions, key=len)
```